# Solution Verification for Radius of Convergence of $\sum\frac{n^2x^n}{2\cdotp 4\cdotp 6 \cdots 2n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

**The Question:**

Find the radius of convergence and the interval of convergence of $\displaystyle\sum\frac{n^2x^n}{2\cdotp 4\cdotp 6 \cdots 2n}$

**My Work**

$$\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right| =\frac{(n+1)^2|x|}{n^2(2n+2)} = \frac{n^3(1/n + 2/n^2 1/n^3)|x|}{n^3(2+2/n)}$$

which will approach $0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$ for all values of $x$ which implies Radius of Convergence $=\infty$ and Interval of Convergence $=(-\infty,\infty)$

**My Question**

Just looking to see if I made any mistakes.

Comment: You lost absolute value bars. They should still be on the $x$. Otherwise it looks good. Note the terms are $\frac{n^2x^n}{2^nn!}=\frac{n^2}{n!}(x/2)^n$. So you have something like the series for $(ax^2+bx+c)e^{x/2}$.

Comment: Thanks Alex. Looking at it, it doesn't really seem to affect my answer. Am I missing something?

Comment: No, it doesn't affect the argument. But if the limit had been greater than $0$, then to write it up in a way that makes sense, the absolute value bars would still play a role.